# Some information about SQL instruction in JDBC in a Spring application

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am studying how to implement CRUD operation on a database in Spring using JDBC following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

It is quite clear but I have only a doubt about how the SQL query are specified:

For example, in the **create()** method of my **StudentJDBCTemplate** clase the query is declared in the following way:

```
String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
```

this is quite different from the classi SQL statment that is:

```
insert into Student("Andrea", 25);
```

I have read about the use of the "?" placeholder that is used to prevent SQL injection and I have understand how this insert instruction work (it is very intuitive...)

I would only know if the instruction used in this tutorial is JDBC or Spring specific form or what about it?

Thank you

Andrea

Comment: `insert into Student("Andrea", 25)` isn't a valid insert statement in any SQL dialect I know.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statements using ? as a placeholder for parameters are a standard JDBC feature. Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) (and the JDBC javadoc) to understand what JDBC offers.

Spring-JDBC adds JdbcTemplate over plain JDBC, which helps in handling exceptions, closing resources, generate objects from rows, etc. It also adds support for named parameters, which are not supported by plain JDBC.

Classes in the packages `java.sql` and `javax.sql` are standard Java classes. Classes in the package `org.springframework` are Spring-specific classes.